# Uk airport visa multiple entry?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-free-entry, brazilian-citizens

I have a family friend who is visiting the U.K. He is a Brazilian National and stayed with me in the north of england for about 3 months. He returned to Barcelona for a few weeks as his dad needed to go to Brazil for work.

He’s since returned to the U.K. as he never got chance to go to London which he really wanted to see.

On his initial visit he was issued a 6 month tourist  visa. After he returned the second time he was issues another stamp. Are these visas multiple entry? And specifically does this mean he has 6 months from his initial visit? Or does the new stamp mean he’s been granted a further 6 months from when he returned?

Comment: Each time you enter and exit the UK, your new entry is fresh and you are bound by the amount of time given you on your entry stamp. It is as simple as that

Comment: His visa will say whether it is multiple entry or not.

Comment: @MattBlack Brazilian nationals can enter the UK visa-free as a visitor for up to 6 months. Https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa Your friend should however be careful not to give the impression that he is effectively living in the UK through frequent or successive visits -see V4.2 of the Immigration Rules https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you say, my interpretation is that **what your friend has/had is not a visa**, but a *Leave to Enter* issued at the border when he arrived without a visa. Visas for the UK are always be applied for *in advance*.

(The word "leave" is here used in the slightly archaic meaning of "permission").

Your friend's *first* Leave to Enter automatically lapsed when he left the Common Travel Area. Its 6-month duration is not relevant anymore.

He successfully applied for a *new* Leave to Enter when he returned from Spain. Its duration governs how long he can stay in the UK *now* without overstaying.

---

**Beware,** however: If he told the immigration officer at the border that he would stay for less than 6 months then he should stick to what he told. If he changes his plans and stays longer than he said he would, *even though it is legal for him to do so*, it can create problems for him on *later* visits. The *next* time he tries to enter the UK, he may be questioned about what caused him to change his plans, and refused entry if they don't like his answers. We have seen several concrete cases of people who were refused for this reason.